# Polarity of 1,2-dichloroethane

Tags: physical-chemistry, polarity

I don't understand how 1,2-dichloroethane is non-polar. Both the carbons have tetrahedral arrangements of atoms and I think there should be an overall dipole. Kindly explain why isn't there a net dipole?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry SE site! When you ask, it is expected you have thoroughly searched and thought about the topic, providing explicit summary of partial answers/ideas/thoughts you have got until then. It is quite common requirement across all StackExchange sites.

Comment: I have provided my thoughts

Comment: Non-polar does not mean having zero dipole moment. Chloroform with significant dipole moment is frequently considered as non polar ( or little polar among non polar ) solvent in context of fuzzy sets of non polar and polar solvents..

Comment: If these are thorough thoughts after thorough search, I am curious how the shallow ones would look like.

Comment: Besides the comment above (non polar is more a classification of solvents etc, and might even include characteristics other than just electrical dipole moment...) consider that even a molecule with net overall zero dipole moment can locally be decomposed in fragments, and ultimately bonds, that do have electrical moment dipoles. In short, it is just a vectors sum. For the actual case, you can think of freezing the molecule in a conformation that indeed has a moment. But in reality, those are averaged out by rotation.

Answer (score 1):

The dipole moment is a vector property, with arrow-like direction and absolute value.  On a local scale, *within* a chloromethyl group, there is a permanent dipole moment.*

You may define a *global dipole moment* about the molecule, too.  This then is the vector sum of all local dipole moments.

However, the two chloromethyl groups are bound together *via* a $\ce{C-C}$ $\sigma$ single bond.  Since the energetic barrier for a rotation is low, if the substance is in solution/melt/or gaseous state, there is continuous rotation between these two groups.  Thus, the time averaged global dipole moment of the molecule cancels out:

[image]

The situation from hot solution/melt may be well different from the one in the solid state and in the crystalline state (an ordered form of  the solid state).

*) Up to you which convention of direction of the vector you choose here.  For this question, it however is irrelevant.